# Generate mapped types from const Object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following object ( this defines the Angular routing / pages. Some have params that can be replaced.):

```js
const ROUTES = {
  PAGE_NO_PARAMS: '/hello/page/two',
  PAGE_R: '/about/:id',
  PAGE_Z: '/page/page/:param/:id',
  PAGE_N: '/who/:x/:y/:z/page',
} as const
```

Can I create a type of valid page types from this object that ignores the params (:xxx) in the path with some sort of wildcard?

Ie. create a type like below (but using the `ROUTES` object). I have it already without the wildcard. However, paths with params resolved ie. `/about/xxxxx` do not meet the `type` check`

```js
type ValidRoute = '/hello/page/two' | '/about/${string}' | '/page/page/${string}/${string}'| '/who/${string}/${string}/${string}/page'
```

In summary, I would like to map though each property in `ROUTES` and create a type that replaces `/:any string/` with `/${string}`

I hope this all makes sense. I'm trying to replace runtime errors with build errors.

Comment: So... there are two problems for us to solve or something? I don't quite get which one is the issue.

Comment: That should certainly be possible, did you try? I suggest you look into template literal types, especially together with `infer`, to extract the parameters, and then various other features, like conditional types and recursion, to put everything together.

Comment: [Please choose a primary question to ask and remove the other one or move it to its own post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).  Otherwise this might be closed as needing focus.

Comment: Moved 2nd question to it's own question > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73804290/generate-a-list-of-types-interfaces-from-a-mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some recursive conditional types to process the path. Wen we encounter `:name` we can replace it with a `$string}`

```
type MakeValidRoute<T extends string, R extends string = ''> =
  T extends `${infer Head}/:${infer Name}/${infer Tail}`?
    MakeValidRoute<`/${Tail}`, `${R}${Head}/${string}`>:
  T extends `${infer Head}/:${infer Name}`?
    `${R}${Head}/${string}`:
    `${R}${T}`
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBASgeQKoBUCiBlGBeGBvAWACgYYAFAQQHE0B9AOQVsrgoFkMAuGAcgHoAFgFMANiJB8ADgEMA5kL5QA7iB4AaYqUo1acbv2kAjEAFcofTgEsAJus3lqdAFr6pchTPkWZAJ2kBbCxs7EgcdelclAQlOAA8LAE8LAC83eRCAXxhpCBhQSChiYigEySEYNmkAayEANWkRGzhTKCEAHhQYIVjWsGtc6B9LMFk1eC6eoT6BqCGRnF4eAD4ce07u3v6YAAMAEjxhgDMhHxgACSFpawyLfaOTmHoAoRu7sGPTlGlLEQztgH57KRKjV6o1rM0zO1tnx9l8fn8xns8HAMvsLldXnhBsNZH8lpw1hNNrlkfdThjrrcDu8Hk9-C8AUCdvtUejLlT9jiRn9CaFSMi2XgUH8ikQSmV4C0hLlcCC6g0mtK2hKhCBDvBkOgMABtGoJdUwVWGxCoTAAXSWmj4fAWACJBKJxGkFMoQHaYAAfHZ8IwtWHY2a4v5en2eDzuAPcvFRoM87ahmFRCRcuMx1NzdOBzM3cPbTTFUrlKhCKAASTArR8h2kwCEAGkhAkIB1iVMttGxnA29MYNGFmAhAA3E4rbBEjbt0kZ4PU8mPZ5Y+fw35M-kwEvlysnGt1xvNtowuHfVdd0P0oQEieTXvI6M3ThvD4Lhl-QHr7vei980ikOBi1UKmqIRIVaCg+jIaQ-H8Ft1hvLY4CEUAfGsNpOz7NMlhWBZCFCHUyBgYYYH1Q0UHNbhcN-GAfGlbgUHw80NHXXwAggbhEOQ1DNwrKtdwbJtYIYpYxmjK1QgyYgMj1JtSPNACiylKFwOsSDoNlICalAoRlNU1iVSLE0tUwMSbSNBStJ0qDWJw4hTKomioW4B1hDECRw0UFQ7QAbls20qJYmD2KQkAULaQcRx8ETMJ8ohTKyb1cLs38HNaJzfWMMwgmsbzfKomAArY+BgtCu0bDtKLMyWGK4tDRK-OS2iYAddz3M4AKspy2L6tIAqgs4tpSuy0M7QC8qMMq6rbXi-BcqogA6BbJpgCSupgDAQAZCYAkkEQZRgQ1ujKYBWmsaiZRMEQoFyW0ThonxciiKYYBMCBcRgeRBz8E6zLKMVTIgaILtOxh1h8O7iHyaBqOlAB1SwoAEXSYIodjpUstSbP5FKhFcFrIzaqzAisWwmN-Xr8F4AKeH0QwRGkAR1F4YJ9FiVmeGWyS-ttAHTBEU7bpC7JchMQdYiO76At4WIeAh8AoexuGEaRiAACFUaUiDCfUyjSGx1w-Uy4mQjJrWKKZ2wWbZsYeGly3pY5ogVtynmga6MHBZyfLCd4BJ2csXJ-H916RllgpoahRXEa1gBhdWwM1jHcB18PUt4PhkwseJOCSThUnDY2etNimbep3hafpxmeGSUueHLhmHYyIA)

We use tail recursive conditional types to improve performance of these types in the compiler

Comment: That's great and exactly what I asked. However, do you know of a way to exclude strings starting ':' ? Basically, I want to have a type for resolved paths not paths with parameters still in them.

Comment: @Ewan you mean in `RouteAndParams` ?

Comment: no I mean for this one. Is it possible for the type to not allow for the original path. in other words I don't want to accept any strings with ':' in them when using the type. I want to know that the params have been resolved. This might be a new question though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73815301/typescript-type-exclude-ban-special-characters-in-string-type

Answer (score 0):

[The other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73804320/2887218) is correct.  For completeness, this is how I did it:

```
type SubstParamNames<T extends string, S extends string = string, A extends string = ""> =
  T extends `${infer F}:${infer _}/${infer R}` ? SubstParamNames<R, S, `${A}${F}${S}/`>
  : T extends `${infer F}:${infer _}` ? `${A}${F}${S}` : `${A}${T}`
```

The `SubstParamNames<T, S>` type is a [tail recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) that substitutes all colon-delimited path fragments (starts with a `":"` and ends with a `"/"` or the end of the string) in `T` with the value in `S`, which [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to just `string`.

That gives the following output:

```
const ROUTES = {
  PAGE_NO_PARAMS: '/hello/page/two',
  PAGE_R: '/about/:id',
  PAGE_Z: '/page/page/:param/:id',
  PAGE_N: '/who/:x/:y/:z/page',
} as const

type Routes = SubstParamNames<typeof ROUTES[keyof typeof ROUTES]>
/* type RP = type Routes = "/hello/page/two" | `/about/${string}` | 
 `/page/page/${string}/${string}` | `/who/${string}/${string}/${string}/page`
*/
```

And if it matters, you could change `string` to something else:

```
type IfItMatters = SubstParamNames<"/ay/:bee/cee/:dee/eee", "XXX">
// type IfItMatters = "/ay/XXX/cee/XXX/eee"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.8.2#code/FAFwngDgpgBAygVwEYGcQAUCGAnTBbAOXyhQB4AVGKADxCgDsATFGNbAS3oHMAaeK2g2asQHbjAC8IsbxgBBAXSYs2nLpJgAiTQD5JwGDEo0lwgAYASAN6cAZlGwwAYgF8AXNbsOYAfRcB6T3p7RwAlFzMYAH54ZDQsXEJiMlC+OD5LKzkXa1drOACzHQMYNyNFIRZMr0dXDxtg7z9ImMzs3JyrAsiyts7yCOBgAGMAe3o0GFCAeQBVcgBROA0rEvQ5AHEFnwJpn3XQuQBZODKAcn8ACygAGxvR-whMLih-EAB3UbOeNc3t0PO-kwSFGCBA-jc7EY31+Wx8AC1AU8Xo9nq83E9EhCoTDDOs4QRAe9Lg83NQIWAIQAvVEvGEuGCYFhjCYgIbgaBTUF0FhSRCoDA4fBEPAkUgcqCjWxTOaLOAAbQA1lAwFKYBK1TN5ksALrFfwAKnVkFgoXQGglXLBJA0miut3utNeH1GmhgAB8YGYgSCwYErKpuBEPTADN7ka8I-7A1wAtYY8HPd7iQ946I1HGA+mg9Hs7GnWZgAb-OyTTAAJK2csgI6YEB0bC82IChLC5KkO2YSluJBQV7DPsQxiDvtQTR8TQADWnumA-n8xs5lertfrDibncp08n-gHr23-lHmiAA)