# Generate a list of types / interfaces from a mapping

Tags: angular, typescript

Given the following object:

```js
const ROUTES = {
  PAGE_NO_PARAMS: '/hello/page/two',
  PAGE_R: '/about/:id',
  PAGE_Z: '/page/page/:param/:id',
  PAGE_N: '/who/:x/:y/:z/page',
} as const
```

Is it possible a list of types / interfaces for each `route` so that the developer is restricted to the valid params for the selected route.

Ie. generate a type from `ROUTES`  that has the same outcome as `type RouteAndParams` below.

```js
interface PageNoParams = {
   route: '/hello/page/two'  // no params
}

interface Param1 = {
   route: '/about/:id',
   params: { id: string } // required params
}

interface PAGE_Z = {
   route: '/page/page/:param/:id',
   params: { id: string; param: string } // required params
}

interface Param3 = {
   route: '/who/:x/:y/:z/page',
   params: { x: string; y: string; z: string } // required params
}

type RouteAndParams = PageNoParams | Param1 | PAGE_Z | Param3;

// Some examples of expected results / errors when using generated type

// should NOT error
const routeWithParams: RouteAndParams = {
   route: '/page/page/:param/:id',
   params: { 'param': 'blah', 'id': 'xxx' }
}

// should error as unexpected param 'x'
const routeWithParams: RouteAndParams = {
   route: '/about/:id',
   params: { 'id': 'xxx', 'x': 'xxx' }
}

// should error as param 'y' is missing
const routeWithParams: RouteAndParams = {
   route: '/who/:x/:y/:z/page',
   params: { 'x': 'blah', 'z': 'blah' }
}
```

I hope this all makes sense. I'm trying to replace runtime errors with build errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some recursive conditional types to process the path and extract the parameter from each path:

```
type Routes = MakeValidRoute<typeof ROUTES[keyof typeof ROUTES]>
 // = "/hello/page/two" | `/about/${string}` | `/page/page/${string}/${string}` | `/who/${string}/${string}/${string}/page`
 
type GetInterfaceKeys<T extends string, R extends string = never> =
  T extends `${string}/:${infer Name}/${infer Tail}`?
    GetInterfaceKeys<`/${Tail}`, R | Name>:
  T extends `${string}/:${infer Name}`?
    R | Name:
    R

type MakeRouteAndParams<T extends Record<string, string>>  = {
  [P in keyof T]: {
    route: T[P],
    params: Record<GetInterfaceKeys<T[P]>, string>
  }
}[keyof T]

type RouteAndParams = MakeRouteAndParams<typeof ROUTES>
// type RouteAndParams = {
//     route: "/hello/page/two";
//     params: Record<never, string>;
// } | {
//     route: "/about/:id";
//     params: Record<"id", string>;
// } | {
//     route: "/page/page/:param/:id";
//     params: Record<"id" | "param", string>;
// } | {
//     ...;
// }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBASgeQKoBUCiBlGBeGBvAWACgYYAFAQQHE0B9AOQVsrgoFkMAuGAcgHoAFgFMANiJB8ADgEMA5kL5QA7iB4AaYqUo1acbv2kAjEAFcofTgEsAJus3lqdAFr6pchTPkWZAJ2kBbCxs7EgcdelclAQlOAA8LAE8LAC83eRCAXxhpCBhQSChiYigEySEYNmkAayEANWkRGzhTKCEAHhQYIVjWsGtc6B9LMFk1eC6eoT6BqCGRnF4eAD4ce07u3v6YAAMAEjxhgDMhHxgACSFpawyLfaOTmHoAoRu7sGPTlGlLEQztgH57KRKjV6o1rM0zO1tnx9l8fn8xns8HAMvsLldXnhBsNZH8lpw1hNNrlkfdThjrrcDu8Hk9-C8AUCdvtUejLlT9jiRn9CaFSMi2XgUH8ikQSmV4C0hLlcCC6g0mtK2hKhCBDvBkOgMABtGoJdUwVWGxCoTAAXSWmj4fAWACJBKJxGkFMoQHaYAAfHZ8IwtWHY2a4v5en2eDzuAPcvFRoM87ahmFRCRcuMx1NzdOBzM3cPbTTFUrlKhCKAASTArR8h2kwCEAGkhAkIB1iVMttGxnA29MYNGFmAhAA3E4rbBEjbt0kZ4PU8mPZ5Y+fw35M-kwEvlysnGt1xvNtowuHfVdd0P0oQEieTXvI6M3ThvD4Lhl-QHr7vei980ikOBi1UKmqIRIVaCg+jIaQ-H8Ft1hvLY4CEUAfGsNpOz7NMlhWBZCFCHUyBgYYYH1Q0UHNbhcN-GAfGlbgUHw80NHXXwAggbhEOQ1DNwrKtdwbJtYIYpYxmjK1QgyYgMj1JtSPNACiylKFwOsSDoNlICalAoRlNU1iVSLE0tUwMSbSNBStJ0qDWJw4hTKomioW4B1hDECRw0UFQ7QAbls20qJYmD2KQkAULaQcRx8ETMJ8ohTKyb1cLs38HNaJzfWMMwgmsbzfKomAArY+BgtCu0bDtKLMyWGK4tDRK-OS2iYAddz3M4AKspy2L6tIAqgs4tpSuy0M7QC8qMMq6rbXi-BcqogA6BbJpgCSupgDAQAZCYAkkEQZRgQ1ujKYBWmsaiZRMEQoFyW0ThonxciiKYYBMCBcRgeRBz8E6zLKMVTIgaILtOxh1h8O7iHyaBqOlAB1SwoAEXSYIodjpUstSbP5FKhFcFrIzaqzAisWwmN-Xr8F4AKeH0QwRGkAR1F4YJ9FiVmeGWyS-ttAHTBEU7bpC7JchMQdYiO76At4WIeAh8AoexuGEaRiAACFUaUiDCfUyjSGx1w-Uy4mQjJrWKKZ2wWbZsYeGly3pY5ogVtynmga6MHBZyfLCd4BJ2csXJ-H916RllgpoahRXEa1gBhdWwM1jHcB18PUt4PhkwseJOCSThUnDY2etNimbep3hafpxmeGSUueHLhmHYyIA)

We use tail recursive conditional types to improve performance of these types in the compiler

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
type ParamNames<T extends string, A extends string = never> =
  T extends `${infer F}:${infer E}/${infer R}` ?
  ParamNames<R, A | E> : T extends `${infer F}:${infer E}` ?
  A | E : A
```

`ParamNames<T>` is a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) that turns a string including colon-delimited path parameters into a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of those parameter names.  For example:

```
type Test = ParamNames<"/ay/:bee/cee/:dee">
// type Test = "bee" | "dee"
```

Then you can turn this into your route-and-params pairs with another conditional type:

```
type RouteAndParams<T extends string> = T extends unknown ?
  ParamNames<T> extends infer S extends string ?
  [S] extends [never] ?
  { route: T } :
  { route: T, params: { [K in S]: string } }
  : never : never
```

It's a little fiddly because we suppress the `params` property if `ParamNames<T>` turns out to be `never` for a particular member.  Let's test it:

```
const ROUTES = {
  PAGE_NO_PARAMS: '/hello/page/two',
  PAGE_R: '/about/:id',
  PAGE_Z: '/page/page/:param/:id',
  PAGE_N: '/who/:x/:y/:z/page',
} as const

type RP = RouteAndParams<typeof ROUTES[keyof typeof ROUTES]>
/* type RP = {
    route: "/hello/page/two";
} | {
    route: "/about/:id";
    params: {
        id: string;
    };
} | {
    route: "/page/page/:param/:id";
    params: {
        id: string;
        param: string;
    };
} | {
    route: "/who/:x/:y/:z/page";
    params: {
        x: string;
        y: string;
        z: string;
    };
} */
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.8.2#code/FAFwngDgpgBACgQwE4ILYDk1QM4B4AqMUAHiFAHYAm2M2ISAluQOYA0MAgkaRdbfU2YwAvDHJQAblCQA+EcBgxCJMlRoADACQBvJgDNpMAGIBfAFw79hgKImA9JfIGkMAEon1MAPwL4yNJioOLiu7FwAPjDWcmZK3Kp8WrpOhqYWyc5RHt6+EVEwsRzAoJCw+DggIn4oGFh4AER2CGB2ZgBGUFB2AMadrZSd9TLAdnYw4NBKFVX1HVD1MJH1A-PFE7CuAPYArmQcVIg1eMo8avyMLHKiJwk02+QA1uSbAO7kOYqHAXUEciq8NCsLgAyvEAedBB8YABtYEAXTBZ2h4ikSARPkU2hgSB2ZFihBMBV8WJxuyg+PYEH8qGwsSx0IA0jAmDB4bE6BchISTL5YijDHzJNJit1NuQ6G4APIAVXw1lBom0vjgHAA4tYAProSUalWuDgAWWBsQA5HYABZQAA2Vs2dipzC6IBemxNrGVas1rlNTTauNaDEobo96o1AC0fQ6ulHWlSagGg+7Pp6tT6Xua7WZiK0WmYAF72hCO4OEhA0UXikBrUpuOBVLZk-aUL403DrTZ6KWy+XQh5QMAd8alQeuGVy+HDOwAKiHk1cdcVvkUpLxMEalptdpjzs29QA3MBCZElYpl7jyWvff6zIH90uYHG0LSYCfT2-A+yBCwD2+TAejy+94rhejQxjGZiPqgCZ3m+kHPq+b6KB+ELfvesHUp+nI-qef6HosgFvsBsSNOmmbZmYuYFlGMGnnBdJoaexCYYI2GITAYDMahbGKHmnHMKxMC4YSU52MUIxjNgGbbFalAwNqyhIDiSDABWErAQA6gwIDmi2z7zlUr5ETAZpgUWXQQdSCbBoodEvsZkEmqabRWgg5pusZgaOcZxA+SagmHsUoy0FJMlEIpmwuGWMD3CQ0DdGQsmQd5JoqWKannpp2m6QATLE+mLmeZI+ggfq7FZSYPtS8EeUGpo+cQ7kmg1dW+f5PLicFOyhdISkwFFSUmmAfkMDQqAjdggipZW2IZVpOlVQAzHlC4ETNRXGXYpGtORlGFsWFW2ViTVeSazmuY1eYnWdbltcAQA)