# Typescript type - exclude / ban special characters in 'string' type

Tags: typescript

I would like to generate a type that allows only a specific format, but with only the standard letters / numbers - `string` seems to allow any string character.

```js
// this is the type that is currently generated
type Path = `\path\${string}\page\random` | `\path\page\${string}`;

/*
Unfortunately, the above type allows all the below cases. 
But I don't want to accept anything with a ':' or a rogue '/' as well as meeting the above formats.
*/

// should be fine as params value has been resolved.
const path1: Path = '\path\hello\page\random';

// should be fine as params value has been resolved.
const path2: Path = '\path\page\somethingelse';

// should error - as it is a path with params (character ':' indicates param name)
const path3: Path = '\path\:id\page\random';

// should error - as it is a path with params (character ':' indicates param name)
const path4: Path = '\path\page\:param';

// should error too as there is an addition page '\' on the end
const path2: Path = '\path\page\somethingelse\and';

// Basically, I would like to ban the characters ':' and '/' from the 'string'.
```

Comment: Not really possible unless you are willing to use  a function to create the path.  There are no negated types in typescript. So you can't express `string` but not starting with`:`

Comment: Let's go the other way and only allow the other 144,695 characters!

Answer (score 4):

Well, I couldn't find a non-generic type solution. So I made a dummy function that saves us from passing generic parameters around. I made 2 types one is for banning things from URL and the second one is for forcing the URL shape not containing banned types

```js
type Banned = `${string}${':'|'/'}${string}`; // you can add more characters 
type GenericPath<T extends string> = `\\path\\${T extends Banned ? never : T}\\page\\random`

function getPath<T extends string>(str: GenericPath<T>): GenericPath<T> {
  return str;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAQgQwHZKgExgXhgAwCQDeAziAE4CWSA5gL6EDkAXPQD70D0r9AOt-XcTKVaOANyhIsAOJRUFAMYAFBCAAWAHgAqMKAA8QstERgkK1AHxZcvCCtW9C2vQaRH4yVBgD8MVADcoUhhGGE0aGwQqKF5SZDQAewBbHBgWa25bNQiohwInfUNjRBR0GB9-QODQmhxgYHYAKmAAVSQAM3jSEABXJBUoABswABoYNVgEACN4gLHJGAQBgfiAd2NFgbHVWEnB1Zh5BCIoIgA6GGA4bpAYAEkYBKR6G5XkG5B4hfl5KAgb5DAamEMBW5DUCxgTHoME6ENI8So3VgHGhRxBg02aMSUCgIGB4wW01mHVIiRUZ2ADXYdXY7BMqni3QGGF2MDalAmxlssUSxj8iyRMFUaN2shgpBO8QGATQp2A8niSBIMEyqgAjFYoiBlGoABQ8DJ2XjbJbxbLRbixVxJegASnE9TpRAZTJZsHZqAWXIQPL5AtgwuMoqQ4sl0vQcoVSpuqoATABmTW4nWqXWQiJZQ05bhEJK41TCQbHO0O2n0xnMnSkeFBAC0XpgYMb6xVdhBYNUrd9MF18mFsXkBiCUMbrnIhwM3p5vgQ2Nt8sVytV8ewWpT+oz9m4jHIaHNMTiNvtNKdLsrgRrMHraKb5Bbqvb4O5s+Mvf7CEHlRHlDQ4-6U9nGc5wXaNWzUAAWJNtTsNMDVVfdt2fRISxPctXSrS8Pk+NFxglZsFhDBA0F-PFFVbKJ0z4GEQwJQwQKXOwAFYoPXSj4KzC1c2xIFqCLC04hQ4A2l6QdyDItc7C0HQClcYxTGEcxdVMEIZDkccUy0cxbRU2RAnUyTNEsAhgBgUMelIENTHEGggA)